# detection of failing nodes in the WSN using cooja

Tags: contiki, cooja, contiki-process

I want to create a project on contiki cooja for the detection of failing nodes in WSN which files I must use to create it.

Comment: It would be better if you can give some idea of what you want to implement.

Comment: av92 for an algorithm to detect failing nodes i do not know how i can implement it on cooja which files i have to use how to do that because i am a beginner on this software

Answer (score 0):

You may implement your logic in udp-client.c and udp-server.c files of rpl-udp project under contiki/examples/. You just need to include desired header files and use them.